# How to filter array of items by another array of items in swift

Tags: swift, array-filter

I have a model named Item and Tag.  Item has multi tags.  I need to filter array of items by another array of tags.  Tags to be used for filter are given by array of string.

I googled but couldn't find answer to solve my situation.

```
struct Tag {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

struct Item {
    let id: Int
    let tags: [Tag]
}

func filter(items: [Item], contains tags: [String]) -> [Item] {
    // Need to implement filter
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chose 1 in 2 option of return:

```
     func filter(items: [Item], contains tags: [String]) -> [Item] {
        items.filter { (item) -> Bool in
            let tagNames = item.tags.map({ $0.name })
            return tags.allSatisfy(tagNames.contains)
            return Set(tags).isSubset(of: Set(tagNames))
        }
    }
```

Comment: The `map` is wasteful. You can just do: `tags.allSatisfy { tag in item.tags.contains(tag) }`

Comment: @Alexander the tags is [String], but item.tags is [Tag]

Comment: so then: `tags.allSatisfy { tag in item.tags.contains(where: { $0.name == tag.name } }`

Comment: @Alexander Thank you, but it should be: tags.allSatisfy { tag in item.tags.contains(where: { $0.name == tag })}. And if writing like this i think the onwner of this question will hard to understand

Comment: Yeah, I would extract that predicate into a named function like `hasTag`, so it could read like `tags.allSatisfy(item.hasTag)`

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to arrange the code to function with a Set of tags instead of an array of tags. How it would be possible?